# xfce4: Keyboard application shortcut to run emacs does not export the current user's environment variables

Tags: shell, emacs, xfce

I have emacs bound to Ctrl-Alt E. I also have some environment variables exported in ~/.bashrc. When running M-x getenv, I get different environment variables not defined in ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bashrc` is normally only sourced for interactive shells.  Put your variables in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.